# How create a CoreBundle in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

To be short, i would like to know if it's possible to the same way CakePHP do it. Having a "CoreBundle(Appcontroller)" which get execute every time whichever is the route or the controller called.

I want this to be able to generate variables that will be add to the variable send to the twig template. 
I looking for something like this to avoid to generate this function in each controller and i don't want to use the {% render %}

Sorry if the question/answer is obvious ^^

Comment: In Symfony, you use kernel listeners for this sort of thing: https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html  And as a side note, I think you will find that you really don't need to do this.  Might also take a look at writing a custom twig extension.  But it certainly won't hurt to start out with listeners.

Comment: use a listener to kernel.view event that get template and modify or add some arguments send to twig look at this to understand all the cycle:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel.html#component-http-kernel-kernel-view

Comment: and some tutorial that uses kernel.view event https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony-journey/kernel.view-event

Comment: A custom Twig_Extension defined as service with the necessary data to determine the values and either adding the result as global variables or simple Twig functions to retrieve the values in a template could be a clean way to do this. https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html

Comment: Thanks but the thing is if i use kernel.view then all of my controller musn't send antthing in return and that's not want i want. I would like to have "normal" controller with processus interfering with them before the reponse is send

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a service and register that service as a symfony global variable.

```
# app/config/config.yml
twig:
    # ...
    globals:
        # the value is the service's id
        user_management: '@AppBundle\Service\UserManagement'
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/global_variables.html

Then from twig you can call to it in the following way:

```
{{ user_management.username }}
{{ user_management }} <-- this will call the method UserManagement->__toString()
{{ user_management.prettyPrint() }} <-- this will call the method UserManagement->prettyPrint()
```

Comment: This isn't really what i was thinking nevertheless i'm going to do it. Thanks :)

Comment: This is the closest solution to what you asked. I do not know why you refuse to use render controller in twig or creating your own twig extension as that will be a better opinionated way of doing it as others recommended in the comments.